# AWS (Java): Alternative for Lambda to exec stored proc

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am trying to execute a stored proc already present in my oracle database from AWS lambda. But to complete the execution, it may take longer than 5 minutes which is a problem since AWS lambda has a max 5 min time limit. Is there a way to asynchronously execute this stored proc or an alternative aws solution?

Comment: Even if Lambda allowed a longer run time it sounds like your Lambda would be doing nothing but waiting for the vast majority of the run time.  How often do you need to run this stored procedure?  How real time do the results need to be?

Comment: The stored procedure would not run too often, maybe once a week. If there is a way i can just start the stored proc and exit from the lambda, that works too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken directly from a [rather old link](https://it.toolbox.com/question/how-to-run-oracle-pl-sql-in-background-on-the-server-from-client-092009) it looks like you can do something like:

```
DECLARE
L_jobno INTEGER;
BEGIN
Dbms_job.submit (
L_jobno,
'BEGIN your_procedure( argument_list ); END;',
Sysdate + interval '1' minute );
Commit;
END;
```

According to the description this will fire off `your_procedure` in 1 minute in the background.  The key is the `submit` method.  However, this is for 10g - your version may have something different.

I would setup a Lambda to run this from a [CloudWatch Event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Scheduled-Rule.html) that is scheduled when you need.  The Lambda could be very small as it just needs to fire off this procedure and exit.  I presume that you then have something else that will know when the output from the procedure can be read.